# Django override save method problem that create two different ids for the meeting

Tags: python-3.x, django

I had override a save method for my **Meeting** model which will generate a random id for the **meeting_ID** whenever user create a meeting.

The save method itself is successful but the problem is that somehow the override **save()** method generate two random ids instead of just one for the created meeting. Meaning that when I click on Save button, it will create two identical meetings with different **meeting_ID**.

I don't know what is the issue as I'm a beginner for Django.

Thanks in advance.

**Model.py**

```
    class Meeting(models.Model):
    
        MEETING_STATUS = (
            ('Coming Soon', 'Coming Soon'),
            ('Live', 'Live'),
            ('Closed', 'Closed')
    
        )
        meeting_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{6,6}$')], null=True)
    
        meeting_title = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
        meeting_date = models.DateField()
        meeting_time = models.TimeField()
        meeting_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    
        meeting_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=MEETING_STATUS)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
        
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.meeting_ID
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            meetingID = random.randint(100000,999999)
            if not Meeting.objects.filter(meeting_ID=str(meetingID)).exists():
                self.meeting_ID = str(meetingID)
                print(self.meeting_ID)
                super(Meeting, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    
    
    class Resolutions_Meeting(models.Model):
        reso_ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        resolution = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        meeting_id = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, related_name="has_meetings", on_delete=CASCADE, null=False)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.meeting_id)
```

**Views.py**

```
class MeetingsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Meeting
    template_name = 'meetings/create_meetings.html'
    # fields = ['meeting_ID', 'meeting_title', 'meeting_date', 'meeting_time', 'meeting_desc', 'meeting_status']
    form_class = MeetingForm
    success_url = None


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(MeetingsCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['meetings'] = ResolutionsFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['meetings'] = ResolutionsFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        meetings = context['meetings']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            # print(self.object)
            if meetings.is_valid():   
                meetings.instance = self.object
                meetings.save()
        return super(MeetingsCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('host_dashboard')
```

**Template/formset.html**

````
```
    {% load static %}
    
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                .delete-row {
                  align-self: center;
                }
              </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
            <table class="col-md-9" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                {{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
                
                    {% for form in formset.forms %}
                            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
                                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <td>
                                    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                            {{ hidden }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
                                </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                
                </table>
            <br>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
                    addText: 'add another resolution',
                    deleteText: 'remove',
                    prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>

```
````

**template/create_meeting.html**

````
```
    {% extends 'meetings/main.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <html>
        <head>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            {% block content %}
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Create Meeting
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% crispy form %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>

```
````

Comment: An additional note, in your model, it is meaningless to use `null=True` inside field `meeting_ID` because you set `primary_key=True`  Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key).

Comment: I noticed that, thanks. I already upload the templates for the form. There's not much that I change in the template as I follow the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form_valid()` method seems wrong: Apparently, you use `save()` method twice so this is why you create two instances. The first `save()` method should be

```
form.save(commit=False)
```

so you do not create an instance on the database. This is what `commit = False` does. It is useful because you can manipulate the data after posting a form by a user. Then you can use the second `save()` method to create the instance on the database. But I think you only want to validate the form data.
Right now, I cannot test your code but I think it must be like:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    meetings = context['meetings']
    if meetings.is_valid():
        response = super().form_valid(form)   
        meetings.instance = self.object
        meetings.save()
        return response
    else:
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

If it doesn't work, then there is another mistake apart from the one I mention. I can edit my answer in that situation.

Comment: I tried your method but still get error saying "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."HOST_RESOLUTIONS_MEETING"."MEETING_ID_ID")". Seems like the database does not get any value from my meeting_ID. Do I need to override the save() method for meetings.save() instead?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use `transaction.atomic()`? I'm asking this because I didn't use it before? Maybe I can handle with another way.

Comment: No, I follow this example for the reference [link](https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6) to create the form. I try to create a form that allow user to create meetings with the resolution in one form.

Comment: Could you also add the template related to the form part? You can do this by editing your own question.

Comment: I noticed that this code ```meetingID = random.randint(100000,999999)``` executed two times when form is submitted. I try to see the meetingID value by print(meetingID) and got two random ids for the meetingID's value.

Comment: I'm sorry not to test my code. I edit my code part. Could you try it?